# proverbial idiom that fits the point that "Main contractor asking (polite forcing) subcontractor to spoon feed his own duty in its entirety"

Tags: expressions, idioms, proverbs

In business, a main contractor is the one who takes up the responsibility of the whole project which he understands he can undertake in its entirety, some without and part with help of a subcontractor. And thus while understanding the scope, he has full idea of the project execution and knows which all instances to subcontract.

Now in a given situation, it is such a the contractor (due to some forces) is appointed as the main contractor. He is clueless of the project but for 10% (and that is exaggerated %) of the jobs , appoints a subcontractor. In doing so he starts to question (even complete reliance) on the subcontract for his own scope too.

Imagine the contractor is a hotel management company and the subcontractor is a experienced ironing company in hotel business engaged for ironing the clothes which is one part of the scope of the hotel management company. How would you expect hotel management company to be spoon-fed by the ironing company in hotel management business scope (which is 90% and a underestimated %).   In this context I am looking preferably for a proverbial idiom that fits this narrative.

Point that needs to get across is the irony that "a main contractor asking subcontractor to spoon feed in entirety for his own scope".

Comment: Do you mean _do someone's dirty work_?

Comment: I don't think that 'spoon feed' is the best term to use for what the management company is trying to do. ' Spoon feeding' is the practice of giving someone else something that they need in small quantities but without the recipient having to do anything to get it. 'Spoon feeding' is a disadvantage to the feeder. Even 'drip feeding' which is the practice of providing someone else with what they need in amounts which are too small isn't really what you're looking for. It is a disadvantage to the recipient but not what's happening. I think it's an example of "mission creep".

Comment: @BoldBen It is like pot forcing kettle to utilize itself for cooking food (which is pot's job). The kettle and pot are both open fire/cooker but while pot is normally used to cook food, the kettle is used for tea or water. Here that means simply that the very responsibility you (pot is) forcing the other (kettle) of, you (Pot have to fulfill yourself.

Comment: @user405662 although the phrase does fit for doing other's duty, it does not denote the main contractor's dishonesty and his guilty of dumping of responsibility equally.

Comment: As I said that's not 'spoon feeding'. An example of a contractor having to spoon feed a subcontractor would be a situation where the main contractor was having to interpret  the details of an architect's drawing for the benefit of a structural steel subcontractor who would normally be expected to have the skills to read it. That is the subcontractor is incompetent or lazy. In your case it's the main contractor who is incompetent or lazy. That's not spoon feeding.